# Unittest Tkinter File Dialog

Tags: python, unit-testing, user-interface, tkinter

## Question

Is there any way to automate a `tkFileDialog` selection to run it through `unittest`? The following is the only use of `tkinter` in my application:

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
types = [('Comma Separated Values', '.csv'), ('All Files', '*')]
filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,
                                        filetypes=types)
root.destroy()
```

**Edit**: I didn't mention that this part of the code was trapped in a method call from a class outside my control.

---

## Background

I've built a local app that creates an http server on `localhost` and runs its GUI with HTML/CSS/JS in a web browser. Because of browser restrictions, I can't use the built-in file dialog and so have to send this request through Python. I want this to run on a OSX with the built-in Python 2.5. I'm not very familiar with `Tcl/Tk`.

### Attempt #1

If I could get to the underlying widgets, I could generate the clicks like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167019/generate-a-click-event-in-tkinter). However, looking at the [dialog source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5accb0ac8bfb/Lib/lib-tk/tkCommonDialog.py), it appears to me that the `Tcl` call in lines 48-50 is blocking. Is this a correct assumption?

### Attempt #2

I thought there might be a way using `Tcl` commands directly through `root.tk.call`. Since I'm on `Python2`, I think the underlying `Tcl` is a single call to `tk_getOpenFile`. Would I have to ensure the `Tcl` interpreter is threaded? Is there any `Tcl/Tk` command that can help me out here?

### Attempt #3

I could implement the file selection from scratch using `os.listdir` etc. (Probably in a separate HTML page communicating back and forth with the server). It would be more than a little painful and hopefully avoidable.

---

## Solution

Based on A. Rodas's answer below, I came up with the following:

```
import tkFileDialog
old_dialog = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename
try:
    tkFileDialog.askopenfilename = lambda *args, **kw: filename

    # First test dialog cancelled
    filename = ''
    method_that_calls_tk()
    # run some assertions

    # Next test a valid file name with valid contents
    filename = self.VALID_FILENAME
    method_that_calls_tk()
    # run some assertions

    # Now test a valid file name with invalid contents
    filename = self.INVALID_CONTENTS_FILENAME
    method_that_calls_tk()
    # run some assertions

    # Now test an invalid file name
    filename = self.INVALID_FILENAME
    method_that_calls_tk()
    # run some assertions
finally:
    tkFileDialog.askopenfilename = old_dialog
```

Comment: What platform is this on? It's somewhat possible to inject events on X11, but with other platforms (i.e., where the true native dialog is used) it's exceptionally difficult. An easier approach would be to completely mock out `tkFileDialog`…

Comment: This would be on X11. I wound up mocking the `askopenfile` function. Out of curiosity, do you have a link or resource where I could read up on injecting events on X11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unit testing of Tkinter code is not an easy issue. For instance, the [IDLE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html) does not have a proper test suite, even though it is part of the standard library. Since you mention that this is going to be the only use of Tkinter in your application, I'd suggest to make unit tests for the outcome of this code: the value of `filename`.

For instance, you can have a test for a .csv file, and another one for an incorrect file extension. Since `tkFileDialog` returns an empty string if it is closed by the user, add also a test where `filename = ''`.

```
import unittest

class TestFileDialog(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_dialog_closed(self):
        filename = ''
        # ...

    def test_incorrect_extension(self):
        filename = '/path/to/another/filetype'
        # ...

    def test_csv_extension(self):
        filename = '/path/to/correct/file.csv'
        # ...
```

Comment: This helped me come up with a much simpler, more effective solution. I've put it as an edit to my question in case anyone stumbles across this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could just patch the calls to tkinter:
patch tk.Tk() because most CI's will error because they don't have displays.
Also patch the file dialog so you can simulate return values and that it is being called with what you expect.

```
@patch('your_module.tk.Tk')
def test_your_stuff(self, Tk)

    with @patch('your_module.tkFileDialog.askopenfilename') as file_dialog:
        expected = 'expected return value'
        assert expected = your_function_calling_file_dialog()

        file_dialog.assert_called_once_with(whatever, you, expect, it, to, be, called, with)
```