# Unittest Tkinter File Dialog for Python 3.5

Tags: python, tkinter, mocking

How do you use mock unitest to mock filedialog.askopenfilename() or filedialog.saveasfilename()?  The same question was answered in the following link for Python 2.x. 
[Unittest Tkinter File Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114182/unittest-tkinter-file-dialog)

The solution does not work for Python 3.5 which is what I am using.

I tried both MagicMock and Patch from unittest and nothing was working. Please see my code below.

```
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from unittest.mock import patch

# @patch(filedialog.askopenfilename)
def test1(self):
    try:
        filedialog.askopenfilename = MagicMock(return_value="")
        app = class1()
        app.method1()
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

@patch(filedialog.askopenfilename)
def test2(self, mock1):
    try:
        # filedialog.askopenfilename = MagicMock(return_value="")
        app = class1()  
        app.method1()  #method1 has filedialog.askopenfilename in it
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

Inside method1, it calls askopenfilename.  I would like to make askopenfilename returns "".

I would greatly appreciated any help.

Answer (score 1):

I figure out how to do it.  I need to specify the class name before askopenfilename.

```
    from unittest.mock import Mock
    class1.askopenfilename = Mock(return_value='')
    # Inside class1, method1 uses askopenfilename to open up file dialog box
    class1.method1()   # method1 will call Mock(return_value='') instead of askopenfilename and return ''
```