# TkInter file dialog test with PyTest

Tags: python, tkinter, pytest

I am developing an command line application (using `click`). Inside my app, I have 1 function that pops-up a `tkinter` file dialog for user to select file/folder.

Is it possible for me to do a unit testing on that function using `pytest`? How can I replicate the user file selection in the test function?

Possible related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114182/unittest-tkinter-file-dialog), but using `unittest`.

Thanks!

Comment: The linked `unittest` solution looks ok, have you tried that approach?

Comment: @stovfl Hmm, yeah looking around it seems that pytest supports `unittest.TestCase`. I didn't know so I wrote this question, I will try that tomorrow.

Comment: @stovfl Looking at it again it seems that they didn't 'mimic' the file selection, but they use filename to replace the file selection option. In my case I have the open file dialog integrated in my method, is there any way to test this?

Comment: You mean test the GUI, simulating mouse clicks?