# How to execute python tkinter button without clicking mouse?

Tags: python, tkinter

I build a GUI application, there is some button and they perform some task. Now i want to perform that mouse click with out clicking that mouse. like with the help of any int number. like if i put a=1 than button 1 will clicked if i put b=2 than button 2 will clicked. How can i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a click event in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167019/generate-a-click-event-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To press the button use its `invoke` method.

```py
button.invoke()
```

Comment: can you please show me sir how can i use this function?

Comment: Thats exactly how you use it. To click the button simply call ```YourButtonName.invoke()```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Robert's answer of using the `invoke` method, you can also directly call the button's function.

Assume the button is defined as follows:

```
button = Button(master, text="Hello World", command=callback)
```

Then, you can just call the function `callback` with `callback()`.